# I want to store my images(multiple) into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form written in PHP. The form data which a user fills in is saved directly into a MySQL database, except for the images and the drop-down options.

My problems are:

1. to save images or their paths into the database
2. to retrieve those images
3. to save drop-down options into the database

[The form looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHQvO.jpg).

And this is the HTML code for the form: (form.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var categories = [];
            categories["startList"] = ["Rental","Sale"]
            categories["Rental"] = ["Residential","Commercial"];
            categories["Sale"] = ["Commercial","Residential"];
            categories["Residential"] = ["Flot","Independent"];
            categories["Commercial"] = ["Play & Plug","Baseshare"];
            categories["Biography"] = ["Play & Plug","Bareshare"];
            categories["Fiction"] = ["Flot","Independent"];
            var nLists = 3; // number of select lists in the set

            function fillSelect(currCat, currList) {
                var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
                for (i = step; i < nLists+1; i++) {
                    document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
                    document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
                }
                var nCat = categories[currCat];
                for (each in nCat) {
                    var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
                    var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
                    nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
                    nOption.appendChild(nData); 
                    currList.appendChild(nOption); 
                } 
            }

            function init() {
                fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
            }

            navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="60%">
        <form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="tripleplay">
        <tr>
            <td width="44%">Full Name : </td>
            <td width="56%"><input size="25" type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Rental Type:</td>
            <td>
                <select name = 'List1' onchange = "fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
                    <option selected>Make a Selection</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <select name = 'List2' onchange = "fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
                    <option selected>Make a Selection</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <select name = 'List3' onchange = "getValue(this.value, this.form['List2'].value, this.form['List1'].value)">
                    <option selected >Make a Selection</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Area : </td>
            <td><input size="25" type="text" name="area" id="area" /> sq.ft.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Owner Mobile / Landline</td>
            <td><input size="25" type="text" name="ownermobile" id="ownermobile" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>E-mail</p></td>
            <td><input size="25" type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Pictures of Property</td>
            <td>

                <input type="file" name="image_one" id="image_one" />
                <input type="file" name="image_two" id="image_two" />
                <input type="file" name="image_three" id="image_three" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Other details you would like to share about your property:</td>
            <td>
                <textarea size="25" name="otherdetail" id="otherdetail" cols="45" rows="5">
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and my process form is looking like this (process.php)

```
<?
if( $_POST )
{
  $con = mysql_connect("","","");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("", $con);

  $users_fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
  $users_area = $_POST['area'];
  $users_ownermobile = $_POST['ownermobile'];
  $users_email = $_POST['email'];
  $users_image_one = $_POST['image_one'];
  $users_image_two = $_POST['image_two'];
  $users_image_three = $_POST['image_three'];
  $users_otherdetail = $_POST['otherdetail'];

  $users_fullname = htmlspecialchars($users_fullname);
  $users_area = htmlspecialchars($users_area);
  $users_ownermobile = htmlspecialchars($users_ownermobile);
  $users_email = htmlspecialchars($users_email);
  $users_image_one = htmlspecialchars($users_image_one);
  $users_image_two = htmlspecialchars($users_image_two);
  $users_image_three = htmlspecialchars($users_image_three);
  $users_otherdetail = htmlspecialchars($users_otherdetail);

  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `vkrental`.`Owner_detail` (

`fullname` ,
`area` ,
`ownermobile` ,
`email` ,
`image_one` ,
`image_two` ,
`image_three` ,
`otherdetail`
)
VALUES ( '$users_fullname',
    '$users_area',  '$users_ownermobile', '$users_email', '$users_image_one','$users_image_two','$users_image_three', '$users_otherdetail'
    );";

  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h2>some text.</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

and mysql database table is looking like this

```
CREATE TABLE `Owner_detail` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fullname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ownermobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `image_one` blob NOT NULL,
  `image_two` blob NOT NULL,
  `image_three` blob NOT NULL,
  `otherdetail` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: `need some modifications in this files for saving images(or images path) and drop down options`: What are those modifications?

Comment: how to save images into mysql database with out leaving this code(or adding some code with this)

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend that you don't save the images in the MySQL database. Instead I would suggest you upload the images to your server or use a service like Amazon S3 / RackSpace Cloud Files and then store the link to that specific image in your database.

Large websites like Facebook / Twitter / etc don't store images in the DB. It add's unnecessary workload to the DB when it's not required.

You can use the following to upload your image and save it into MySQL:

```
require_once('amazon-web-services-api/sdk.class.php');

$AWS_KEY        = 'KEY';
$AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET';

$s3 = new AmazonS3(array(
    "key"    => $AWS_KEY,
    "secret" => $AWS_SECRET_KEY
));

$s3 -> set_region('s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com');

$bucket   = 'bucket_name';
$filename = 'picture.jpeg';

$response = $s3 -> create_object($bucket, $filename, array( 
                                'fileUpload' => $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],
                                'acl' => $s3::ACL_PUBLIC
                                ));

if($response -> status == 200){
    // The file was Uploaded and Saved to S3 OK!!
    $file_location = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'.$bucket.'/'.$filename;

    $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (id, image_url) VALUES ($ID_NUMBER, '$file_location')";
    $result= $mysqli -> query($query);
    $num   = $mysqli -> affected_rows;

    if($num == 1){
        // The data was saved OK - redirect or say thanks, whatever you want.
    }else{
        // Display an error, log an error, do whatever is necessary 
    }

}
```

To retrieve the data you would just write a `SELECT` statement to fetch the data back. You will then have a column in your table that contains the image URL. You can then drop the image URL into an `<img src="LOCATION" />` tag to display it

Comment: then i ask one. when a user submit some images how to save that images and path into sql server and how to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

You would save them like everything else. 
When you add your categories to the database and fetch them to generate the dropdown lists you can reference the ID, if not you should save the option value itself and try to match your stored option with the existing categories while generating the dropdown-list.

You should change your database structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Owner_detail` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fullname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ownermobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `otherdetail` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `image` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `owner_id int NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_owner_has_image_idx` (`owner_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_owner_has_image`
   FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id` )
   REFERENCES `Owner_detail` (`id` )
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE)
);
```

So you can save as much images per user as you want. If you would do it your way, you would limit yourself to three images per user.
When you want to move your categories you can add the cols to you Owner_detail table where you reference the chosen category / dropdown-option.